# Basic Python Script in Google App Engine to get the GET parameters and use it accordingly

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I tried a number of times googling and searching over whole internet, but didn't find anything relative.
I just want to get the GET parameters of the current page.
just like if we get **$query = $_GET['q']** when we write into that page in PHP.
Actually after getting this result I want to use decision making statements.

Comment: Do you mean inside a `RequestHandler`?

Comment: yes, i am totally dipressed, i am searching from 2 days, but still i didn't find any answer working at my place.

Comment: Did you saw the [Request Class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass) doc?

Comment: maybe i don't understand even a single word say they, because whenever i copy and paste the codes, some error shows on localhost:8080 like <type 'exceptions.NameError'>. I am from PHP backgoround

Comment: @jeeveshkumar - If you tried code from Request Class, you should mention what you tried and the error messages you got. Then we could help you get it right; otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: I think you need to follow the getting started guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**URL: example.com?color="green"&flavour="mango"**

```
color_from_url = self.request.get('color')
flavour_from_url = self.request.get('flavour')
```

Is that what you mean? If not, can you give an example of the source data (the URL) and the data you want out of it.

Comment: I just wrote **print self.request.get('y')** and uploded it to App engine, and got the error **Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.**

Comment: Even, when i run this script on localhost:8080, then it shows <type 'exceptions.NameError'>

Comment: print does not mean anything in app engine. Where are you expecting it to print to? Here are some complete working example projects. It's quite different to a non-cloud enviroment. http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/

Comment: it's not a script you can run. It's an example showing that given that URL hitting a request hander that would be how you retrieve the contents. Unless you've created a handler with that in it and gone to it you can't execute that code. There is no request unless you are in a handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass

Comment: i pasted full script and run, but nothing happened. only blank screen